# MySQL Workbench: Refactoring Script

Tags: mysql

We have to make some changes to our databases (creating tables, Running special SQL queries).

Is there some way in MySQL Workbench to import a structure, edit it with a graphical interface and then getting some piece of SQL Code that I can use to transform my old structure into the new structure?

**To explain my problem a bit further:**
I need a way to transform my MySQL database structure to a new structure (adding databases and values into those tables) without interrupting the production environment for too long.

I would prefer a solution in MySQL Workbench (I'm using version 6.3)
but also accept any other answer to do this (for free)

Comment: you can export your existing DB as a script (without data if you like), import it to another DB (on another server if you like). Then in workbench every time you apply a change to the DB structure using the GUI, it pops up with the actual SQL script that will be executed. You can copy/paste this SQL out into a file each time, and so build up a big patch script to alter your structure.

Comment: I recall using an option called "Reverse Engineer" (4+ years ago) which would produce an ERD by analyzing the DDL used to create/define the tables. You'd be able to work on the diagram and then let Workbench generate SQL based on your new/modified diagram. Is that still available?

Comment: Reverse Enginnering the old structure worked. I got a Model and can edit the tables. Exporting this will result in "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" statements with all columns. I want "ALTER TABLE" statements that will add the newly created columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, **I actually found a solution!!**

What I was looking for is called an "**SQL ALTER Script**" or a Schema Sync.

Steps to generate a SQL Alter Script with MySQL Workbench:

1. Open MySQL Workbench
2. Click *File* -> *New Model*
3. Click *Database* -> *Synchronize With Any Source*
4. Click *Next*
5. Select a SQL Dump File as *Source* (this is the new structure)
6. Select a SQL Dump File as *Destination* (this is the old structure)
7. At *Send Updates To* select a Folder and Filename where the ALTER Script will be placed.
8. Click *Next*
9. Click *Next*
10. Make sure *default_schema* is checked and Click *Next*
11. Click *Next*
12. Preview your SQL Code and Click *Next*

You now successfully generated your SQL Alter Script and it got saved into the specified file.

**But Note** that you will have to open the SQL File in an editor and replace *default_schema* with your database name